# Share localhost:port loadbalancer with kubernetes

Tags: docker, docker-for-mac

Do you know if it is possible to share localhost:port with kubernetes.

I am running kubernetes in docker-for-mac, and when creating a loadbalancer - everything works great for containers running in kubernetes via localhost.

Sometime I like to test some code, in a container running just as a `docker run` - where I am opening ports with -p 8080:80 something.

Now the question is will it conflict with the localhost running k8s loadbalancer - if I run on ports not open to kubernetes loadbalancer?

My guess is, that it does not work - as I am experience some problems reaching ports running with `docker run`.

If it does not work, how do you `docker run` along side Kubernetes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re using the Kubernetes built into Docker (Edge) for Mac, it is the same Docker daemon, and `docker run -p` will publish ports on your host as normal.  This should share a port space with services running outside Docker/Kubernetes and also with exposed Kubernetes services.

You need to pick a different host port with your `docker run -p` option if you need to run a second copy of a service, whether the first one is another plain Docker container or a Kubernetes Service or a host process or something else.

Remember that “localhost” is extremely context sensitive; I’d avoid using it in questions like this.  If you `docker run -p 8080:80 ...` as you suggest, the host can make outbound calls to the container at localhost:8080; the container can make outbound calls to itself at localhost:80; and nothing in any Kubernetes pod or any other container can see the service at localhost on any port.